# How to build a talend job which contains a tRunJob Component?

Tags: batch-file, talend, jobs, data-integration

I'm using talend Open Studio for Data Integration 6.4.1
I've created a job which contains a `tRunJob` component which calls another job. So I've built the job (*Construire le job* in yellow on the attached image), it creates a batch file that I can run whenever I want. The problem is that when I run the batch file, it doesn't take into account the job specified in the `tRunJob` component.

How to do to include all the jobs on the batch file?

[image: here's the image showing how to build the job and create a batch file]

Comment: You only need to build the parent job (which contains tRunJob). It will take care of calling the child job. You only get one batch file for the parent. What do you mean it's not being included ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @iMezouar. I built the parent job but the tasks that I've developed under the tRunJob seem to haven't been executed. I don't understand why

Comment: Hi iMezouar. Thank you for your help. I retried doing exactly what you said and it works very well. i still don't understand what was the problem. Thanks